# Windows firewall blocks outbound connection that is allowed by a rule

Tags: windows-7, firewall, windows-firewall

I have configured Windows Firewall to block all outbound connections. I have then created "allow" rules to enable certains applications to create outbound connections. Unfortunately it seems that some connections that should be allowed are still blocked and I don't understand why.

I have a simple rule to allow Windows Problem Reporting:

- Enabled: Yes
- Action: Allow the connection
- Programs: `C:\windows\system32\wermgr.exe`
- Protocol type: TCP (6)
- Local port: All Ports
- Remote port: All Ports
- Local IP address: Any IP address
- Remote IP address: Any IP address
- Profiles: Domain, Private, Public

Nevertheless, after creating this rule, a connection was blocked and logged in the event log:

```
The Windows Filtering Platform has blocked a connection.

Application Information:
    Process ID:     7440
    Application Name:   \device\harddiskvolume3\windows\system32\wermgr.exe

Network Information:
    Direction:      Outbound
    Source Address:     192.168.1.23
    Source Port:        31532
    Destination Address:    65.55.53.190
    Destination Port:       80
    Protocol:       6

Filter Information:
    Filter Run-Time ID: 184645
    Layer Name:     Connect
    Layer Run-Time ID:  48
```

Given the rule that was created specifically to allow `wermgr.exe` to connect I don't understand why the connection was blocked. How can I modify the rule to allow the connection to succeed?

By the way, this is not an issue isolated to `wermgr.exe`. Once in a while I see blocked connections for other applications even though I have created rules for them also. Luckily most of the time the rules work as expected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After asking for help in the [Windows Filtering Platform (WFP)](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wfp/threads) forum on MSDN I learned that you can capture the activity of WFP (which the firewall employs) using the following commands:

```
netsh wfp capture start
netsh wfp capture stop
```

The resulting log file is XML which makes it human readable and from that file I learned that `wermgr.exe` is blocked by the rule *WSH Default Outbound Block* with the description *Blocks all outbound traffic for services who have been network hardened*. Apparently, this rule takes precedence over my "allow" rule.

I'm not sure exactly why `wermgr.exe` is affected by the Windows Service Hardening default rule but I assume that one of the hardened services execute `wermgr.exe` to perform a task of connecting to the server at `65.55.53.190` (a Microsoft IP address), and `wermgr.exe` is then blocked just as the service would be.